# how to Convert Sql Server .mdf to Access .accdb by running a script

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ms-access, rdbms

we already have a running system with MS Access. Some parts of the database are updated periodically in a centralized way and disseminated via email for each end user to integrate into their system.

Now I have developed an online version of the Updating part in MVC5 and I want to convert SQL Server ".mdf" back to access ".accdb" and let the end user download the access database.

if anybody knows the workaround please help.

Comment: Sql Server has lots of features that access does not supports, so its not always possible to convert. Are you sure your sql server database does not have any of these features

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it is possible to do it via Export Wizard, but I want it with the button click within my application and script should run for generating the .accdb file and make it available for download.

Comment: I don't think sqlserver is completely backwards compatible. I'd question why you are not pushing your end user to an environment that utilises the sql database.  You could provide them with read only access to SQL that they can use through Excel at the very least:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-with-an-external-data-source-db50d01d-2e1c-43bd-bfb5-b76a818a927b